# Why I get into an endless redirects cycle?

Tags: php, apache, yii2

I installed basic Yii2 application and want to force all connections to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Here my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/main\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)main.html /$1 [R=301,L]

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And in web/index.php I'm adding

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

When I open site I see an error "too many redirects". I check chrome network inspector and I see that from https://example.org I'm redirecting to https://example.org and so get into the cycle

Comment: Is there a reverse proxy or load balancer in front of your webserver?

Comment: I've not looked at it in depth - but I think your issue might be with this line `RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` - the preceding `RewriteCond` won't apply to that rule as they only affect rules that **immediately** follow, so `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]` won't be applied to that rule.

Comment: No any reverse proxy or load banacers.

Comment: I deleted line `RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` and this dont help

Comment: Try restart your browser - 301 redirection is cached by browser, so it may be cache related problem and browser does not even sent request to your server.

Comment: No, I tried on another computer that open site first time - problem not with it

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to redirect http to https in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It redirects all request on port 80 to https.